# Responsive Design - wide tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am doing a proof of concept with responsive design. One web page that I am modifying has some extremely wide tables. I really don't know how to shrink the tables width so there is no horizontal scroll bar in a mobile browser.

I was just wondering if anyone has a solution for extremely wide tables using responsive design. Oh and I wanted to add that I can not hide columns in the table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a question for [ux.se]. Turn here for help needed overcoming the technical challenges, but SO Q/A is not a place to ask for design hints

Comment: Perhaps transposing the table or cutting it vertically will work?

Comment: Depending on the contents of the table, you could probably just have it so that the table can be dragged horizontally without scrolling the entire page left or right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The nicest way to do it is to completely reformat the table:

http://jsfiddle.net/MLZEb/9/

```
tbody, tr, th, td { display: block }
thead { display: none }
td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

td:first-child {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Each `td` will need to have a `data-label` attribute for this to work effectively:  `<td data-label="Favorite Color">Blue</td>`.  Typical `th` elements as column headers are expected to be within a `thead` tag.

Comment: +1 - nice use of `attr()`

Comment: +1 I need to learn using `attr()`, great CSS altogether

Answer (score 2):

[My knee-jerk reaction would be to put the table in a scrollable container](http://jsfiddle.net/GUD3R/). Adding a bit of helper JavaScript to enable moving the contents via a mouse drag would be helpful for desktop users. Mobile users would be able to take advantage of native touch dragging.

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

<sub>CSS:</sub>

```
td {
    padding: 10px;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: +1 - IMO this is the best solution in many cases, especially on touch devices. Swiping to the left is easy/intuitive for users.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to solve the wide table issue is by presenting only essential columns at the beginning and to provide a UI to add additional columns interactively.